# How to convert the created subnets into map data for later code use?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

First I create 3 subnets, I want to convert them into map form for the lookup of the code behind.
such as:

```
[0 = "${aws_subnet.subnet-1.id}" 
1 = "${aws_subnet.subnet-2.id}" 
2 = "${aws_subnet.subnet -3.id}"]
```

```
resource "aws_vpc" "module_vpc" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy = "default"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-1" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.module_vpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-2" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.module_vpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-3" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.module_vpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.3.0/24"
}
```

The following is the code using lookup

```
resource "aws_instance" "server" {
    count = 3
    subnet_id = "${lookup(var.subnets, count.index % 3)}"

}
```

What should I do? thank you all

Comment: Why are you converting them to a map instead of using a list and then accessing them by the index?

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I will try the method you said!

Answer (score 1):

What about an alternative way, which is more extensible based on list:

```
variable "subnet_cidrs" {
    default = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
}

resource "aws_vpc" "module_vpc" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy = "default"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  count      = length(var.subnet_cidrs)
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.module_vpc.id
  cidr_block = element(var.subnet_cidrs, count.index)
}

resource "aws_instance" "server" {
    count = 3    
    subnet_id = element(aws_subnet.subnet.*.id, count.index) # modulo is automatically applied
}
```

I assume terraform 0.12, as you haven't specified any other version.

Comment: The "special power" of the `element` function as opposed to normal list index is that it automatically applies the modulo operation to the given index if it's higher than the list length, so that last expression could potentially just be `element(aws_subnet.subnet.*.id, count.index)`, or else I would probably just write it as `aws_subnet.subnet[count.index % 3].id` if not relying on the `element` function's automatic wrapping ability.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thanks. Didn't know that. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Your answers have benefited me a lot. I am very happy to have your help, thank you.

Comment: @NaviCN No problem. If so, accepting the answer would he appreciated.